# What is the best way to develop a screensharing/presenting app in java or c++ using RTP?

Tags: java, c++, rtp

I am trying to build a server sided HTML rendering based browser much like skyfire. I am evaluating the technologies that I would need to build this. When a user types in a www.yahoo.com on the client box, there is a session started on the server, then i grab the screenshots and send them in a RTP stream back to the client. To do the RTP bit, i started using JMF http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/solutions/ScreenGrabber.html I found out that when i got the RTP stream back on the client, it was extremely slow and sometimes i would get a lot of artifacts in the video stream. Is there a better way to do this than to use JMF?

Answer (score 1):

Well if I correctly understand your problem, you need an efficient way to do the RTP streaming. A really good and efficient library for streaming in C++ is [live555](http://www.live555.com/). To encode your images you can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and eventually its C++/java/JMF binding [FOBS](http://fobs.sourceforge.net/). This way you can have an efficient streaming server.

Answer (score 0):

It's isn't clear which feature of skyfire you want to implement.

If you're streaming a succession of screenshots, and finding it slow, then compress the data which you're sending. Presumably one screenshot is only very slightly different than the previous one: to minimize bandwidth, you should only transmit the delta between each screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Look at VNC/VNCViewer. There is even an viewer applet, and IIRC there was a question here on SO whether it can be done in a Java Desktop Program (as against in a applet in browser)